# Django: User able to sign up in custom registration form even if the email address is already used by another user

Tags: python, django

In my web app, I have a custom registration and login form which I made using HTML/CSS and not Django's `form.as_p` and Bootstrap. I have the following code in `views.py`:

```
def loginUser(request):
    logout(request)
    if request.POST:
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('/dashboard/')
        #otherwise show the user an error message
        else:
            login_message = "Your username or password is incorrect."
            return render(request, 'Meetings/index.html', {'login_message': login_message})
    return render(request, 'Meetings/index.html')

def signUp(request):
    if request.POST:
        username = request.POST['username']
        email = request.POST['email']
        password = request.POST['password']
        password_confirm = request.POST['password-confirm']
        if(valid_form(username, email, password, password_confirm)):
            #create the new user
            user = CustomUser(name=username, email=email, username=username)
            user.set_password(password)
            user.save()
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('/dashboard/')
        else:
            message = "Something went wrong."
            return render(request, 'Meetings/index.html', {'message': message})
    return render(request, 'Meetings/index.html')
```

I have a CustomUser model in models.py:

```
 from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
 from django.db import models

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=70, null=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
```

When a user signs up, a CustomUser is created and they are logged in to the app. However, if another user signs up using an email address that is already taken by another existing user, they are still able to make an account. I want it to be such that each user must have a unique email address, and they cannot make an account with an email address that is already in use. However, I am not sure how to do this. Any insights are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add this clause to your code to restrict the user using two emails

```
       if User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
          messages.error(request, 'That email is being used')
          return redirect('register')
        else:
```

import the User from settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL

Answer (score 2):

You have inherited **AbstractUser** in your **CustomUser** class so by default AbstractUser class have **unique=True** for username field but not for email field. If you need email field unique then you have to define it in CustomUser class like:

```
email = models.EmailField(max_length=70, unique=True)
```

or make validation in your logical code(view.py) like:

```
if CustomUser.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
    messages= 'Error:This email is already being used with us.')       
    return render(request, 'Meetings/index.html', {'message': messages})
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
   if User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
      messages.error(request, 'That email is being used')
      return redirect('register')
```

Answer (score 1):

why you want to define email field again? your class is inherited from AbstractUser that has email field somehow you want.you just add extra fields you want to add to the basic user model and in your settings.py file, set the default user authentication model to the new class that you created like below:

```
    AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'appname.CustomUser'
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the email field to include `unique=True`

```
email = models.EmailField(max_length=70, null=True,unique=True)
```

You will have to run your migrations again I believe

Answer (score 0):

For one in the model, this field needs the `unique = True`, property. As well as running a queryset that sees if the user exists. `User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():`

and rejecting the update if it does

So basicly combine the answers of the other two posters and you will be in line with best practice!